# Ionic Angular NFC Changedetection Problem

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, nfc

I have a problem using an actual Ionic Angular in combination with NFC reader.

I can successfully read the NFC Tag with the example provided in:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc

The Problem that i have is, that after the reading of the NFC somehow the Angular ChangeDetection is broken and the changes are not displayed. When i click on a button that does nothing, the changes are displayed.

I know i can trigger the ChangeDetection manually, which would work, but then i would have to trigger the ChangeDetection everywhere in the component, which i think should not be the case.

Does anyone have an idea what i am doing wrong?

First i thought maybe it has something to do with the observable, but i tried adding a interval observable, which works just like expected.

Template:

```
<p><ion-button (click)="startNFC()">start NFC readermode</ion-button></p>
<p><ion-button (click)="startNFCListener()">start NFC listener</ion-button></p>
<p><ion-button (click)="startInterval()">start Interval</ion-button></p>
<p><ion-button (click)="doNothing()">do nothing</ion-button></p>
<p>
  {{nfcReading}}
  {{nfcTag}}
  <ion-spinner *ngIf="nfcReading"> </ion-spinner>
</p>
```

Code:

```
startNFC() {
  console.log("startNFC");
  this.nfcReading = true;
  let flags = this.nfc.FLAG_READER_NFC_A | this.nfc.FLAG_READER_NFC_V;

  this.readerModeSub = this.nfc.readerMode(flags).subscribe(
  tag => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tag));
    this.nfcTag = this.nfc.bytesToHexString(tag.id);
    this.nfcReading = false;
    this.readerModeSub.unsubscribe();

  },
  err => {
    console.log("Error reading tag", err);
    this.nfcReading = false;
  }
);
```

}

```
doNothing() {
// this really does nothing... it is just to demonstrate that this triggers the changedetection
}
```

i get can see that the subsciption event is triggered in console, but it is not shown in the HTML.
When clicking the do nothing Button. The tag is shown.

I created a fresh type=angular blank project and test on a Google Pixel 3a hardware.

i have uploaded a sample project to demonstrate my problem.
https://github.com/autlunatic/Ionic-NFC-Android-Test/

Comment: This is probably a lame work-around, but could you stick the contents of `tag => {DO THE THINGS}` into a function (like `doNothing()`) so that a function gets called and fires off detection? Also, does sticking a `console.log()` in the subscribe response show that those things are happening when they should?

Comment: Yes i can see the console.log from the subscribe response. I just tried that, it does not change anything to extract the function. i guess the detection on noNothing() is called because of the interaction with the App.

Comment: i found a weird and even lamer work-around. i subscribe to a interval(250) before reading which also does nothing other than unsubscribe when this.nfcReading is false. this triggers the detection. 
    this.readingInterval = interval(250).subscribe((_) => {
      if (!this.nfcReading) {
        this.readingInterval.unsubscribe();
      }
    });

Comment: I hadn't considered the app interaction being what kicked it. Your interval trick is handy. I have no doubt there is a better or obvious way, but I don't know what it would be (without manually handling change-detection). Would Angular let you fire off change detection manually, while still relying on it handling it automatically everywhere else?